# How to Convert an Extended Partition to Separate Logical Partitions?

Tags: windows-8.1, partitioning, mbr

I have two disks, with MBR.
The first disk has a part of it as an extended partition, and the whole second disk is extended.

I am trying to install Windows 8.1 to my second disk, but the installation refuses, as I am attempting to install to a logical partition in an extended partition.
My question is, how do I remove the extended status and retain the partition order and data?

(For those of you wondering, Windows install reports `Setup was unable to create a new partition or locate an existing one` after selecting `Disk 0 Partition 3` for the location of installation)

Will Windows still act up because I have an extended partition? If I keep part of my second extended partition and have two extended partitions, will Windows refuse to read/install/etc.?

Answer (score 3):

> How to Convert an Extended Partition to Separate Logical Partitions?

You cannot. Logical partitions only exist in an extended partition.

For MBR you have these options:

1. A primary partition (up to 4 of them), or
2. Up to three primary partitions and one extended partition. That single extended partition and contain multiple logical partitions.

Now I suspect that your real intendtion is to convert the logical partition in that extended partition to a primary partition. The normal way for this is:

1. Backup all data
2. Verify that the backup works.
3. Wipe the logical partitions and then the extended partition.
4. Create a primary partition
5. Restore all data.

> how do I remove the extended status and retain the partition order and
>   data?

You cannot. You can try this however:

1. Backup all data
2. Verify that the backup works.
3. use partition magic or similar software to shrink the logical partition.
4. Next shrink the extended partition (which now has space since you shrank the logical partition).
5. Create a primary partition of at least 20GB (windows 7 has enough space with about 16GB, but some spare diskspace is a good thing).
6. Install windows on this primary partition.
7. Keep moving data from the volume on the logical partition to the newly created primary partition. Shrink that partition as space becomes available. Grow the primary partition as space becomes available.

It is more risky and probably much slower than just wiping and restoring from backup though.

Comment: Would I be able to do something along the lines of disconnecting the MBR disk, and then create a new MBR on the disk with the extended partition and create separate partitions using the data provided in the EBRs preceding each logical partition?

Comment: Another note: I already tried to do your second suggested method, however the tools I used weren't able to shrink the extended partition. Any suggestions on which tool to use for this?

Comment: Back in the XP are I did that with partition magic. Not sure if that still works on a modern system. And regardless of tool used, I recommend starting with a good backup.